# How am I able to access a static variable from another file?

Tags: c, static-variables

How am I able to access a static variable from another file? Doesn't static variable have a file scope?

```
bash-3.2$ ls
a.c  b.c

bash-3.2$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>
static int s = 100;
int fn()
{
/*  some code */
}

bash-3.2$ cat b.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.c"
extern int s;
int main()
{
printf("s = %d \n",s);
return 0;
}

bash-3.2$ gcc b.c   

bash-3.2$ a.exe
s = 100
```

Comment: Is it not violating or bypassing the definition of a static variable that it has file scope only and can not be accessed from another file?

Comment: *Never* #include *.c, *.cpp, etc. files as headers.

Answer (score 6):

You have included one file into another - very bad practice. From C compiler point of view, both files form one translation unit, because C preprocessor inserts the content of `a.c` into `b.c`.

In case of two separate translation units, one unit cannot access `static`s of another, but it's not your case.

If you remove `#include "a.c"` line and compile like it should be: `gcc a.c b.c`, you will get `unresolved external` error for `s`.

Comment: Is it not violating or bypassing the definition of a static variable that it has file scope only and can not be accessed from another file?

Comment: Static scope is limited to translation unit. In your case both files are one translation unit.

Comment: As a general rule, I absolutely agree - avoid including source files (as opposed to headers).  However, for unit testing the internals of a source file, including the source file provides the test code with access to the otherwise invisible code (variables and functions) - and can be extremely useful.  But that is a very specialized context.

Comment: @Jonathan: Very specialized and not worth mentioning due to the confusion for beginners who don't yet grasp the concept of TUs.  Also covered under the general rule "Never include implementation (*.c) files as headers" because you're not treating them as headers.

Answer (score 5):

It's from a separate file, but what you're printing is not from a separate *translation unit* as you `#include` the whole of `a.c` from `b.c`.

`static` objects are local to a *translation unit*, which consists of all included files, and not to a single source file.

Comment: Doesn't static variable have a file scope?

Comment: @aks: No, not if you mean source file.

Comment: #include is not the same as the "import" or similar that some other languages support. It's more like assembling a single source file by cut-and-pasting in addition "header" files. It's not the same as linking multiple compilation units together - for that, you use a linker to combine the object files generated by the compiler from your source files. The single-source-file case generally gets made easy - two+ files isn't hard, but you do need to know the compiler options etc, or find an IDE that does that for you.

Comment: @aks: Forget "file scope" and think in terms of translation units (TUs), this use of static means "internal linkage", which you might think of as "TU scope".

Comment: @Steve314: gcc (and most C compilers I've ever used) make it really easy, no matter how many files: `gcc a.c b.c`.  A 15 minute make tutorial that covers implicit rules and CFLAGS covers the rest. (`echo a.exe: a.o b.o >>Makefile && make a.exe`)